# How to create entity relationship for following scenario in Spring data JPA?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

```
@Entity
public class A {
 @column("ID")
 private Long id;
}

@Entity
public class B {
 @column("ID")
 private Long id;
}

@Entity
public class C {
 @column("ID")
 private Long id;

 @column("A_ID")
 private Long aID;

 @column("B_ID")
 private Long bID;
}
```

In C entity following insert are possible

```
ID A_ID  B_ID
 1   1     1
 2   2     1
 3   3     1
 4   1     2
 5   2     2
 6   3     2
```

In above case i want to get parent entity(A or B) from child entity(C)

e.g

```
C c=crepository.findByID(6);
A a=c.getA();
B b=c.getB();
```

How to create relationship in above Entity's?
I hope it is achievable using Spring data JPA.

Comment: have you tried replacing `aID` with `a` which is of class `A` and annotating it with `OneToOne`? (and same procedure for `B`)

Comment: classes A and B only have the id column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this leveraging the `@OneToOne` annotation should do it:

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Column("ID")
    private Long id;

    //other columns, getters, and setters
}

@Entity
public class B {
    @Column("ID")
    private Long id;

    //other columns, getters, and setters
}

@Entity
public class C {
    @column("ID")
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID", referencedColumnName  = "ID")
    private A a;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID", referencedColumnName  = "ID")
    private B b;

    //other columns, getters, and setters
}
```